# Named query not known - Hibernate + JSF

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Fala pessoal,

Estou com problemas ao chamar uma named query, resultando em `org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known`

**Hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lopi?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="org.primefaces_icarus_war_2.0.0PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java::app/icarus</jta-data-source>
    <class>br.lopi.model.Empresa</class>
    <class>br.lopi.model.Usuario</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lopi?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Classe de etidade:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPRESA")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empresa.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Empresa e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empresa.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM Empresa e WHERE e.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empresa.findByNomefantasia", query = "SELECT e FROM Empresa e WHERE e.nomefantasia = :nomefantasia"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empresa.findByRazaosocial", query = "SELECT e FROM Empresa e WHERE e.razaosocial = :razaosocial"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empresa.findByCnpj", query = "SELECT e FROM Empresa e WHERE e.cnpj = :cnpj")})
public class Empresa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "NOMEFANTASIA")
    private String nomefantasia;
...
```

**Onde eu chamo a query:**

```
    public List<Empresa> listar() {
    Session sessao = null;
    try {
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        return sessao.getNamedQuery("Empresa.findAll").list();


    }
    catch(HibernateException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {            
        if(sessao != null && sessao.isOpen())
            sessao.close();

    }
}
```

**Erro:**

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeÃ§Ã£o de recurso no bean gerenciado usuarioController
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:73)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:62)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.primefaces.icarus.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:609)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: Empresa.findAll
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:1368)
    at br.lopi.DAO.EmpresaDAO.listar(EmpresaDAO.java:39)
    at br.lopi.service.EmpresaService.listar(EmpresaService.java:13)
    at br.lopi.controller.UsuarioController.inicializar(UsuarioController.java:25)
    ... 67 more
```

Acredito ser algum problema nas configurações do Hibernate, mas já procurei bastante e não descobri do que se trata.

Se alguém puder dar uma luz, agradeço muito.

Comment: Estranho você ter os dois arquivos XMLs, parece redundante. Tem certeza que seu sistema está configurado corretamente? Ele parece estar ignorando o persistence.xml. Aí, ele não acha a entidade e sua Named Query não é encontrada. Outra coisa, qual classe `Entity` está importando?

Comment: Erra isso mesmo! O persistence.xml estava redundante, bastou mapear as classes no hibernate.cfg e está resolvido.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente tem uma redundância na sua configuração.

Você tem dois arquivos `xml` configurando o Hibernate:

- hibernate.cfg.xml
- persistence.xml

Apenas em casos [muito específicos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808406/2387977) você usaria ambos, referenciando um deles ao outro. Mas o padrão é ter apenas um deles.

Como está usando `SessionFactory`, é [provável](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26918328/2387977) que o sistema esteja considerando apenas o `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Ou seja, a sua configuração está ignorando justamente o arquivo de configuração que você declarou as entidades com `<class />`, o `persistence.xml`.

Uma solução é mapear as entidades no `hibernate.cfg.xml` e, possivelmente, remover o `persistence.xml`.

Outra causa para este erro é ter importado o `Entity` incorreto. Certifique-se que esteja usando o `javax.persistence.Entity`